# Custom spring interceptor

Tags: spring

I want to convert some of our internal API into a <strike>spring bean</strike> spring interceptor that we can use in other projects. This API needs some instantiation and other logic which I want to encapsulate in this <strike>bean</strike> so that we can just put the bean into our app context with necessary propoerties alone, and this will then apply the logic.

I remember having read an article on this somewhere in the past - but cant find it now.
Any pointers to something similar will be helpful

EDIT: Sorry, I meant a spring interceptor, not a bean - my bad - please see my edit. I want to apply this interceptor to another bean dealing in XML messages.

EDIT 2: ANSWER FOUND
found it!

I found the answer to this - we were looking to insert the interceptor at the point where we were calling our webservice. So I looked at the interceptor package in spring-ws and found this end point interceptor interface. We will now implement this interceptor and put our processing logic in the appropriate handle*() method.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/EndpointInterceptor.html

Comment: What sort of interceptor? An http interceptor, or an AOP interceptor?

Comment: I wanted a AOP interceptor - found the link in some old mail.

Answer (score 0):

As with everything in spring, there are a million ways to implement AOP.  Check out the [spring doco on AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html), the section on [declaring aspects in xml](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-schema) may be the most convenient in your situation.  You can configure an aspect

```
<aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="existingBean">
    <aop:before pointcut="execution(* com.package.to.intercept.*(..))" method="existingMethod"/>
</aop:aspect>
```

Or you could create new classes that use the AspectJ annotations and use those aspects to farm off to your actual work to your existing beans.

Comment: Hi, we found a way to write an end point interceptor on our WS, will try this as well.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Found it!</strike>

See this link - http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch02s09.html

This gives the interface that you need to implement and the XML definition.

Found a more suitable answer - see the edit in main question.

Comment: That refers to Spring-Flex (the BlazeDS integration), not Spring in general.